# Table is not getting responsive in bootstrap when switching to mobile screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have create a table in bootstrap in which i have one input field one text area and one button the interface works perfectly for large screens and tablets but it does not work in mobile screen i don't know why its not working.
here is my code .

```
<section class="container">
<div class="">
<table class="table table-responsive" style="display:block;" >
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Tittle:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tittle" style="width:300px;"/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="success">
     <td>Post:</td>
     <td><textarea name="post" style="width:300px; height:150px;"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Post" class="btn btn-success"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</section>
```

Table view of the page.[image: tablet view]
Mobile view of the page.
[image: mobile view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done this the only problem was with the div class="row" and div class="col-lg-3"

```
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Tittle:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tittle" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="success">
     <td>Post:</td>
     <td><textarea name="post" class="form-control" style="height:150px;"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Post" class="btn btn-success"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

See demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Debananda/jJhsL/

```
<section class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Tittle:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tittle" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="success">
     <td>Post:</td>
     <td><textarea name="post" class="form-control" style="height:150px;"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Post" class="btn btn-success"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</section>
```

Mobile Img : [image]

Comment: try this on mobile screen the demo you have shown me is for tablet view please try this on mobile screen it will not work

Comment: I am not sure about the resolution you are talking about. I re-sized the screen in demo link (shared above) to a smaller size yet it didn't give me any scroll bar. can you attach the screenshot.

Comment: The only problem there was i did not wrap the input element in the class row which were giving me the problem to have responsive input size we must have to nest them inside the class .row in this way its going to work

Comment: anyhow vote up is your right thats what i can do for you